# What is the de fact portable external program calling library in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

What is the *de facto* portable external program calling library in Common Lisp?

I found two of such libraries [here](http://www.cliki.net/System%20programming).

- executor;
- external-program.

Any other things?

Answer (score 6):

Newer versions of ASDF come with `run-program` (see [here](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Miscellaneous-additional-functionality.html%20for%20details)).

In ASDF 3 there's a special package for such portability utilities, called `uiop`.